# Identify user with no login or cookies

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to identify the machine which has accessed so the web can be customized for each user?

I mean without using logins or cookies.

Comment: Hi Jaime, I had the same problem. Unfortunately, I did not find a solution. If you come to a conclusion, Please tell me.